# Memory management question

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

Is there a memory leaks when I set an attribut in this way :

```
titleView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 5)];
```

And is there a difference with

```
UIWebView *newWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 5)];
[self setTitleView:newWebView];
[newWebView release];
```

Thanks,

EDIT : 
I'm releasing the titleView in the dalloc function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a property called titleView.

> @property (retain) titleView

First one leaks, unless you release it on **dealloc** (but beware if you are assigning it more than once)

correct one should be:

```
self.titleView =  [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 5)] autorelease];
```

it is always good practice to use self.propertyName as it also releases the old value.

Comment: **[self setPropertyName :]** - calls the same method when assigning value using **self.propertyName**. So there is no difference in memory management between this to approaches.

Comment: actually i was pointing out that, second one (assigning property) is better in memory management. Assigning the instance variable directly is always more risky

Comment: but when I write UIWebView alloc, the retain count is 1. Then when I write titleView = [...] the retain count should be 2. Then I'm releasing titleView in the dealloc function, so the retains count goes back to 1 => memory leak. That is how i see it, but I'm probably wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If `titleView` is declined without **retain** attribute then there is difference.

In first case there will be all ok. In second one - you can't use `titleView` after `[newWebView release]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have declared the proerty correctly:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *titleView;
```

if do:

```
self.titleView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 5)];
```

then you leak but when you do it direct in the ivar like:

```
titleView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 5)];
```

The you are ok.

But you need to release it in the dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [titleView release], titleView = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: You don't need to set `titleView` to `nil` in the `dealloc` method - it will never be called twice :)

Comment: Well there are some long discussions on that part. See: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/09/dealloc.html

Comment: a link please - I'd like to read up on the reasons why people have different views on it!

Comment: Ah, same arguments we have in our office :) Personally, I prefer not to allocate them to `nil` so I can see quickly if I have any memory managements bugs. However, I can also see the benefit or more robust when released code :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse attribute with instance and/or local variable. An attribute (or property) is accessed via `self`, while instance variable is accessed directly by it's name.

In first example there's a leak since I can't see the release message sent to `titleView`. If `titleView` is instance variable you'd release it in `viewDidUnload` method. If it's local - you should release it when adding to some view (like in second example).

In the second example there is no memory leak.